# Thread is still working after it finished the run() method

Tags: java, serialization, java-threads

I want to make a thread that serializes my object.

My thread's run method:

```
    public void run() {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("SaveBook.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(K);
                fos.close();
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
```

The thread class also gets an object K from the constructor.

I get an error when I try to deserialize the object in the main method. So I checked if the thread is still alive, and it is. I think deserialization is not working because the thread is still alive when I try to deserialize.

How I start the thread:

```
SaveRunnable save = new SaveRunnable(K1);
        save.start();
```

How I try to deserialize the object:

```
try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("SaveBook.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            K4 = (Book) ois.readObject();
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
```

**My task is to make serialization in a thread.**

Comment: If you get an error: Please provide a stack trace. Else, we can only guess what may be the problem.